# Magento 2.3.5 Product Search Error: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.3.5, product-grid, magento-admin

I have tried to search a product in common search field of Product list in admin panel, but it throws error message like '**Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state**' in Magento Admin. I've analysed the solution for this issue and found only temporary fix as '**Empty/Truncate ui_bookmark**' table. I have tried this, actually it worked but not as permanent fix.

In future, if user search any string and face the same error, how can we prevent this issue? Please suggest a permanent fix to resolve or prevent from occurring this issue.

Please see the screenshot below[image].

Comment: This is not a problem related to bookmark. When you clear the bookmark, it helps you get out of that error screen because it cleared out the input/your-search

Comment: what you should do is search for the error inside var/log folder, and also, check the network tab in your browsers when you start searching, it may show the error there